# Build nodes and edges from long-format data frame

Tags: r, networking, nodes, igraph, edges

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
ID Order
1  Shirt1
1  Shirt2
2  Shirt3
2  Shirt4
3  Shirt1
3  Shirt1
3  Shirt5
3  Shirt6
4  Shirt1
4  Shirt2
```

From here, how can I generate nodes and edges to later build a weighted graph?

I guess my data should be something like this were the nodes would be columns1 and 2 and the weight column 3. But not sure if this is the best way to build a network

```
Item1  Item2   Weight
shirt1 Shirt     2
shirt3 Shirt4    1
shirt1 Shirt1    1
shirt1 Shirt5    1
shirt5 Shirt6    1
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC we need create the all possible combination by using `combn`, then just `group_by` again find the unique `ID` per pair

```
library(dplyr)

s = df %>% group_by(ID) %>% do(data.frame(t(combn(.$Order, 2))))

s = s %>% group_by(X1,X2) %>% summarise(Weight = length(unique(ID)))
s
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   X1 [?]
      X1     X2 Weight
   <chr>  <chr>  <int>
1 Shirt1 Shirt1      1
2 Shirt1 Shirt2      2
3 Shirt1 Shirt5      1
4 Shirt1 Shirt6      1
5 Shirt3 Shirt4      1
6 Shirt5 Shirt6      1
```